# NullPointerException on OutputStream using BluetoothSocket?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to send data to an HC-05 bluetooth module but am not sure what I'm doing wrong. My main code where the problem lies is below.
I'm trying to just grab some specific text and send it off in bytes.
I've already paired my module before starting the app, and loop through all the paired devices using getBondedDevices() on my BluetoothAdapter and can confirm it is paired.

```
public void send(View view) {
    try {
        Log.d("TAG", "Sending!!!");
        OutputStream os = mConnectionSocket.getOutputStream();
        Log.d("TAG", "Text is: " + mSendText.getText().toString().getBytes());
        // This lines under produces the error
        os.write(mSendText.getText().toString().getBytes());
        os.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "Written...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the code I use to get a BluetoothSocket after confirming the device is connected. mModule is the BluetoothDevice object I want to send data to.

```
       if(isAlreadyConnected) {
        try {
            mConnectionSocket = mModule.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mConnectionSocket.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e ) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "Not connected!");
    }
```

This is the stack trace of the error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.write(BluetoothSocket.java:510)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothOutputStream.write(BluetoothOutputStream.java:85)
            at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
            at **com.test.arduinobluetoothdatasender.MainActivity.send(MainActivity.java:133)**
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error goes away when I comment out this:

```
os.write(mSendText.getText().toString().getBytes());
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong, but it is probably something obvious.

Comment: Suspicious line: `at com.test.arduinobluetoothdatasender.MainActivity.send(MainActivity.java:133)`  Is that the line you commented out?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It throws this error when I put this os.write(mSendText.getText().toString().getBytes()); It works fine when I comment it out, but the point of my app is to send data to the device and this is crucial.

Comment: Did you check `mSendText.getText()` is not returning `Null` ?

Comment: Yep, checked that as well.

Comment: `OuputStream` is also not `null` ?

Comment: You're creating a `Thread` but never starting it.

Comment: Well now I'm embarrassed. Thanks for catching that out. Works fine now :)

Comment: Surely `mSendText.getText()` is already a `String`? No need to call `toString()` on it.

Comment: @EJP If `mSendText` is a `TextView`, `getText()` returns a `CharSequence`.

Comment: Yeah, but it is an EditText and returns an Editable.